# Retrieve the values from JSON String by sending keys dynamically using jackson API?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json string like

```
{
  "profile":{
    "personalInfo":{
      "name":"Sample",
      "address":"XXX",
      "town":"YYY"
    }
  }
}
```

I want retrieve data by sending keys dynamically.
I can able to retrieve by giving key directly. But i don't want that.

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree("aboveJsonString");
JsonNode subNode = jsonNode.path("profile");
```

But i have to give "profile" dynamically. I will get that parameter from api request. Suggest me the approach?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. What do you mean by dynamically? Finding a key value using a programmatically determined value?

Answer (score 0):

When you do not know name of a key in `JSON Object` you can iterate over all elements using [elements](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#elements--) which returns [`Iterator<JsonNode>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html?is-external=true). In your case you have two `JSON Object`s with one key-value pair and you can traverse it like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;

import java.io.File;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .build();
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonFile);
        JsonNode personalInfo = root.elements().next().elements().next();
        System.out.println(personalInfo);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"name":"Sample","address":"XXX","town":"YYY"}
```

Comment: I have json format as: { "key1": {"key1.1": 100}, "key2": {"key2.1":120, "key2.2":11}}. All they keys are dynamic. How do I get keys along with the iterator for the values? elements() gives me only iterator, fieldNames give me only keys, iterator for values has to again be figured out. I want a technique that probably does the same thing at once.